# app doesn't show current location

Tags: arcgis-android

I am trying to build an arcgis nearby places android quite similar to this:
https://developers.arcgis.com/example-apps/nearby-android/. I have make a map portal and import geojson file which placed all my stations location.

But i can't get the app to show my location.

```
package com.utbfyp.webmapapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.view.View;

import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISMap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.LocationDisplay;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.portal.Portal;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.portal.PortalItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MapView mv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mv = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map1);

        LocationDisplay myLocation = mv.getLocationDisplay();
        myLocation.startAsync();

        //use ArcGIS Online as the Portal
        Portal arcgisOnline = new Portal("http://www.arcgis.com");
//create a PortalItem with ArcGIS Online WebMap ID
        PortalItem portalItem = new PortalItem(arcgisOnline, "xxxxx");
//create an ArcGISMap object with the PortalItem
        ArcGISMap myMap = new ArcGISMap(portalItem);
//display the webmap to MapView
        mv.setMap(myMap);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for location permissions and request permission if not granted:

Declare app permission in app manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Check for the permission:

```
// define permission to request
String[] reqPermission = new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION };

// get the MapView's LocationDisplay
myLocation = mv.getLocationDisplay();

// request permission at runtime
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, reqPermission[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  // Start Location Display
  myLocation.startAsync();
} else {
  // request permission
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, reqPermission, requestCode);
}
```

Additionally, you can check that your location display has started:

```
if (!myLocation.isStarted())
  myLocation.startAsync();
```